# keeping jQuery show/hide state on submitting form

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I'm trying to display a HTML block, using jQuery if a checkbox is checked.
All works fine, until I submit the form (it displays form errors based on server-side rules)

But when viewing the page, the block of HTML is hidden again.

How to keep the state of the block of HTML in 'show' when the form is submitted?

I'm using the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Hide div w/id extra
   $(".test").css("display","none");

    // Add onclick handler to checkbox w/id checkme
   $("#yes").click(function(){

    // If checked
    if ($("#yes").is(":checked"))
    {
        //show the hidden div
        $(".test").show("fast");
    }
    else
    {
        //otherwise, hide it
        $(".test").hide("fast");
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do :

Add an hidden input in your form. Change its value when you check / uncheck.

When the page is refreshed through the submit, check the value of the hidden field (via $_POST or $_GET) and add the attribute checked="checked" if needed.

Checkbox should be checked then and the HTML should be visible.

Here's something working for me

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" id="verifyCheckbox" name="verifyCheckbox" <?php
  if(isset($_POST['verifyCheckbox']) && $_POST['verifyCheckbox'] == "true")
  {
   echo 'value="true"';
  }
 ?>/>
 <input type="checkbox" id="yes" 
 <?php
  if(isset($_POST['verifyCheckbox']) && $_POST['verifyCheckbox'] == "true")
  {
   echo 'checked="checked"';
  }
 ?> />
 <input type="submit" />
</form>
<div class="test">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus a facilisis risus. Nam quis sapien turpis, non porttitor ante. In vulputate arcu non diam porttitor vulputate. Aenean leo est, adipiscing a egestas ut, dapibus sit amet purus. Quisque pellentesque mi ac orci placerat congue. Nulla sodales mollis arcu sed viverra. Integer id metus turpis. Vivamus interdum convallis sagittis. Quisque quis tellus ante, a consequat eros. Donec tincidunt luctus dolor. Nulla pulvinar, odio et consectetur dictum, mauris massa vulputate magna, et pretium mauris tortor vel nibh. Donec quis tortor lacus, sed fringilla dui. Duis diam nulla, faucibus vel malesuada quis, auctor nec lorem. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam iaculis tristique mauris vitae facilisis. Nulla facilisi. Nulla non nisl id lacus laoreet auctor sit amet non tellus. Vestibulum quis nibh sed ligula tempor scelerisque. Nunc pretium dapibus convallis. Proin pulvinar, tellus vitae imperdiet rhoncus, elit justo scelerisque libero, nec iaculis lacus turpis ut est.</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Hide div w/id extra
   $(".test").css("display","none");

    // Add onclick handler to checkbox w/id checkme
   $("#yes").click(function(){

    // If checked
    if ($("#yes").is(":checked"))
    {
        //show the hidden div
  $("#verifyCheckbox").val("true");
        $(".test").show("fast");
    }
    else
    {
        //otherwise, hide it
  $("#verifyCheckbox").val("false");
        $(".test").hide("fast");
    }
  });

  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['verifyCheckbox']) && $_POST['verifyCheckbox'] == "true")
  {
   echo '$(".test").show();';
  }
 ?>

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, so I have a slight problem now. I have 3 sections. All have 2 checkboxes, Yes or No, I'd like to show/hide certain sections depending on previous selections, how would I modify your code above?

Comment: So, you have three forms, each form has two checkboxes, and, when submitting, you would like to remember all the checkboxes and change content accordingly, is that it ?

Comment: Well 3 groups of 2, only 2 checkboxes are shown as default, yes and no. Selecting No, displays 2 other checkboxes, selecting one of them, then displays the final 3 checkboxes

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're refreshing the page when you submit the form (e.g., classic form submission). If so, you have three options:

1. Set a cookie when the user clicks the checkbox that stores the checkbox setting; when your page loads, use JavaScript to check the cookie and show/hide the HTML block as appropriate.
2. Have the form include a flag for whether the checkbox is ticked (probably via a hidden input element, or you could append something to the form action), and have the page shown after form submission default the HTML block to showing or hidding as appropriate (via a `style` attribute `display: none` for hidden).
3. Don't use a classic form submission if your user has JavaScript, use an Ajax one instead.

Those are probably in order of least impact to most impact on your current code.

Answer (score 1):

Try triggering the click after binding the click event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".test").css("display","none");

   $("#yes").click(function(){
    if ($("#yes").is(":checked"))
    {
        //show the hidden div
        $(".test").show("fast");
    }
    else
    {
        //otherwise, hide it
        $(".test").hide("fast");
    }
  });
  $("#yes").click();
});
```

EDIT: formating

Comment: This seems to work ok, a part from my checkbox is checked by default. So the div doesn't display until i uncheck and recheck the box

Comment: I also need to extend this to use multiple checkboxes, showing/displaying others

Answer (score 0):

I guess your submit target is the same page. In this case you can use a hidden form variable to decide wheather the block should be visible or hidden when loading the page.